# Postgres Table toast size is too large

Tags: postgresql, json

I want to store some information as JSON in the postgres table. Our application is using a platform. When they started business we store all the data in our db. But now as the application grows we must migrate this huge DB to platform. We have around 50 million rows(in production). But what we need to get out from this migration is just the summary of the whole table.

The old table includes all the information. We will only store duration, occurrence and ID's about the event. The problem is the summary table is just ends up having bigger size than the old table.

In development environment we have around 500 MB of the old table but when I summarize the data to our summary table it ends up having size around 7000MB.

What are we missing about storing JSONB in postgres? Summary table size

[image: summary_table_size]

The main table size is as follows

[image: main table size]

Example json structe is as follows

```
{
    "sil": [{
            "e": "8084",
            "d": 126053168,
            "o": 11
        }, {
            "e": "16907",
            "d": 500838,
            "o": 8
        }, {
            "e": "60000",
            "d": 15000,
            "o": 1
        }, {
            "e": "14500",
            "d": 3955000,
            "o": 21
        }, {
            "e": "16912",
            "d": 396000,
            "o": 1
        }
    ]
}
```

Our stack is Spring JPA and Hibernate Postgres 9.5. We need to update one row each time we encounter an event. We add the duration to the duration of the respective event and we increase the occurrence by 1. I am suspicious if the summary table is keeping so much unneeded information(by us obviously) about row_versions. Each time we make an update it is incremented.

**EDIT 1 Adding table pg_dump results:**
First the summary:

```
--
-- PostgreSQL database dump
--

-- Dumped from database version 9.5.3
-- Dumped by pg_dump version 9.5.3

SET statement_timeout = 0;
SET lock_timeout = 0;
SET client_encoding = 'UTF8';
SET standard_conforming_strings = on;
SET check_function_bodies = false;
SET client_min_messages = warning;
SET row_security = off;

SET search_path = public, pg_catalog;

SET default_tablespace = '';

SET default_with_oids = false;

--
-- Name: event_summary; Type: TABLE; Schema: public; Owner: postgres
--

CREATE TABLE event_summary (
    id bigint NOT NULL,
    agent_id character varying(255),
    date character varying(255),
    row_version integer DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    summary jsonb,
    tenant_id character varying(255)
);


ALTER TABLE event_summary OWNER TO postgres;

--
-- Name: event_summary_pkey; Type: CONSTRAINT; Schema: public; Owner: postgres
--

ALTER TABLE ONLY event_summary
    ADD CONSTRAINT event_summary_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id);


--
-- PostgreSQL database dump complete
--
```

Secondly the main table event_table. I removed some rows

```
--
-- PostgreSQL database dump
--

-- Dumped from database version 9.5.3
-- Dumped by pg_dump version 9.5.3

SET statement_timeout = 0;
SET lock_timeout = 0;
SET client_encoding = 'UTF8';
SET standard_conforming_strings = on;
SET check_function_bodies = false;
SET client_min_messages = warning;
SET row_security = off;

SET search_path = public, pg_catalog;

SET default_tablespace = '';

SET default_with_oids = false;

--
-- Name: event_table; Type: TABLE; Schema: public; Owner: postgres
--

CREATE TABLE event_table (
    id bigint NOT NULL,
    agent_id character varying(255),
    event_no character varying(255),
    event_text character varying(255),
    st_duration bigint,
    st_end_time bigint,
    st_start_time bigint,
);


ALTER TABLE event_table OWNER TO postgres;

--
-- Name: event_table_pkey; Type: CONSTRAINT; Schema: public; Owner: postgres
--

ALTER TABLE ONLY event_table
    ADD CONSTRAINT event_table_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id);


--
-- Name: idx_agent_id; Type: INDEX; Schema: public; Owner: postgres
--

CREATE INDEX idx_agent_id ON event_table USING btree (agent_id);


--
-- Name: idx_agent_id_start_time_end_time; Type: INDEX; Schema: public; Owner: postgres
--

CREATE INDEX idx_agent_id_start_time_end_time ON event_table USING btree (agent_id, st_start_time, st_end_time);


--
-- PostgreSQL database dump complete
--
```

I found out the reason why toast table size is very big finally. It is because we are updating a row very frequently and our autovacuum configuration numbers were not triggering  frequent vacuums. We updated vacuum numbers and I modified my code to do less updates for one row. I am keeping the model in memory and when I reach the intented level I am writing to db. In postgres writing or updating results adding new row to the physically. So thats why it was very big.

Comment: Could you share both tables creation ddl ?

Comment: Yes I will edit but for purposes of information hiding I will remove some parts.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: Postgres 9.5 is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  you should plan an upgrade as soon as possible.

Comment: Perhaps agent_id sould be bigint to an agent table - if it's really an ID ..  reduces your row size / toast quite a bit ...  Where's the JSON going (into the descriptions)?

Comment: Since you cannot disclose details, we cannot answer your question. Perhaps hire a consultant.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe No I am not closing any relevant information. I wrote every column in the problematic table. I am only reading every column from my main table and I am updating the summary table. If there is any information you need you can explain it. I will not change the main table. So it is not relevant here. I will read every column from there and I will use duration and occurrence information from each row and I will update  the summary table.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thanks for reminding that. I will also look into that

Comment: @MrR Sorry i could not understand your point.  Do you mean change type of agent_id to bigint?  The json is summary column

Comment: @gunescelli is agent_id a "key" like thing - in which case make it a key, if it isn't then maybe the field name isn't good.  And you might drop the toast usage quite a bit too...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fail to see why this should be in JSON form at all.

> We need to update one row each time we encounter an event. We add the duration to the duration of the respective event and we increase the occurrence by 1.

I assume that **e** identified the event, **d** the duration and **o** the number of occurrences.

The problem here is that to update just *one* of these entries, you have to update the entire JSON "blob" in that row.  That's likely to be *slow*, compared to a simple, Relational table, like this:

```
select * 
from table1 ; 

+-------+-------+----------+----+
| id    | e     | d        | o  | 
+-------+-------+----------+----+
| 12345 |  8084 | 126053168| 11 |
| 23456 | 16907 |    500838|  8 |
| 34567 | 60000 |     15000|  1 |
| 45678 | 14500 |   3955000| 21 |
| 56789 | 16912 |    396000|  1 |
+-------+-------+----------+----+
```

And, to perform your update:

```
update table1 
set o = o + 1 
, d = d + ? 
where id # ? 
and e # ? ;
```

Comment: Yes maybe we can change json to another table. Because there are 1 million different kind of event, we worried if the table could end up very big. But looks like your proposal would be better.

Comment: If the json column is updated all the time with new stuff added to it, and the JSON is big enough to go to TOAST, you are going to get huge bloat on the TOAST table. I bet most of the 7GB size is bloat. You could check that. But really, Phill is absolutely right, you should get rid of the json and use a real table instead.

Comment: And when you do the summary, you should not do any UPDATES. Just use a query on your main table with sum() and count().

Comment: @bobflux I searched bloating on the TOAST table. I saw that postgres is storing the copy of  older row_versions and if my column is very long it is resulting in bigger bloat. Is it true?

Comment: @bobflux Yes we are doing that. But our main purpose is to eventually get rid of that table and only keep summary table.

Comment: Yes, if you have a json object every time you update it a new copy is created. Expired data is reclaimed by vacuum when it runs, but if you do a lot of updates on big json objects it will bloat like crazy.

Comment: And I mean, you should not do any updates to generate your summary. Just use a query with aggregates on your main table and store the result of that query in the summary table. Incrementing (updating) the summary row for every source row you count is going to be horribly slow. Just use sum() and count().

Comment: Actually we are trying to summarize day by day. We thought we can achieve by this structure of rows:

agentId, date, summary(JSON). 
Your proposal is also a solution. But we are trying to store as little as possible. If we store as a full relational database table we must add assetId and date for each row in your table as you gave as in your example table1. I think storing more columns will be an overhead again.

Comment: Yes, it /will/ be an overhead, but a considerably /smaller/ one than what you currently have.  An Integer and a Date will take up about a dozen bytes between them; just the 'e', 'd' and 'o' identifiers in your JSON take up that much already.  Also, PostgreSQL will be able to /process/ a relational model far more efficiently.